# RestSharp not deserializing a string (always null)

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, restsharp, json-deserialization

I currently tried to get serialized response from a RestSharp PostAsync call like in

```
var responseData = Client.PostAsync<Data>(request).Result;
```

Now, this is what I receive:

```
    {
    "status":1,
    "success":"message transmitted",
    "available":19215,
    "message_ids":"26684730:56798"
    }
```

and this is the "Data" class:

```
public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public int Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public string Success { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("available")]
    public int Available { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("message_ids")]
    public string MessageIds { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("error")]
    public string Error { get; set; }

}
```

I don't know why, but the property message_ids is always null!?
May this be caused by the : in the string, and my this be a bug in RestSharp?

Here is what "Data" looks like:

[image]

Comment: Why would you assume a bug in one of the most widely used REST HTTP clients for C#, and not suspect your own code? Have you considered that you're using the wrong `JsonProperty` attribute? How do you "receive" the JSON? Who generates, sends and processes what here? What are we looking at?

Comment: Well, given the Data class you presented in the question, i bet a dead horse that either the json response you got from the backend/server did actually _not_ contain a "message_ids" json property, or some "fancy" stuff you do with Data instances in your code being responsible for the result you observed. Btw, i also accept dead raccoons for winning this bet. And the screenshot showing the content of some Data instance does _not_ correlate with the presented json data even when not considering "MessageIds" (note the difference in "Available").

Comment: @CodeCaster I did not really assume a bug, but I can't find out why this happens. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction with the wrong JsonProperty attribute.

Comment: @MySkullCavelsADarkPlace You lost! :-) The Json response contains a message_ids string and I do no fancy stuff. The JsonProperty attribute is wrong for ResSharp and I have to use JsonPropertyName instead. Nevertheless, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for restsharp you need JsonPropertyName attribute

```
[JsonPropertyName("message_ids")]
public string MessageIds { get; set; }
```

or if you want to use JsonProperty you will have to use Newtonsoft.Json

```
var response = client.ExecuteAsync(request).Result;

//if you have async method better to use
var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

Data  data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(response.Content);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Of cause I use the await method in real code, I only reduced it to a simple statement running in LINQPAD to reproduce the error.
Yes, using the correct JsonPropertyName attribute fixed it. Since NET6 comes with its own Json classes sometimes I'm mixing this up with Newtonsoft in elder code.
What I still don't understand, is why it worked on "Available", "Status", "Success" but not on "MessageIds" ?

Comment: Ahh, finally I think this is because the JsonProerty was not working on all attributes, but they are named like the attribute, only using an upper letter in front.

status => Status but
message_ids => MessageIds (without _) :-(

Again, thank you pointing me in the right driection.